# XSLT: How to do math on an xpath result in a value-of select statement

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm trying to simply divided a number by 100.  Can I do this without going thorugh a variable?  Have to use XSLT 1.0 to work with BizTalk.

```
<ns0:InvoiceTotal>
    <xsl:value-of select="number(Header/BeginningSegmentForCarriersInvoice/@NetAmountDue) / 100" />
</ns0:InvoiceTotal>
```

Above returns errors:

> Unexpected token '100' in the expression.
>   ...arriersInvoice/@NetAmountDue) /  -->100<--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator for division in XPath/XSLT is `div`. Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(Header/BeginningSegmentForCarriersInvoice/@NetAmountDue) div 100" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed that it's the only math operator that doesn't use the normal symbol.  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp

Comment: Well, it's the *XPath* language, so `/` is kinda taken.